# How to show excel and csv files together for GetOpenFilename file picker?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to allow the user to select multiple files - both `xlsx` and `csv` - however I can't get the popup box to show both file types.

I can only select between `xlsx` and `csv`.

[image]

But I'd like them shown together.

I've tried every combination I can think of, including copying from tutorials, but the `GetOpenFilename` object always fails.

Adding an ampersand `&`

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.XLS* & CSV Files (*.csv),*.CSV", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened")
```

Adding extra quotation marks `"`

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.XLS*" & "CSV Files (*.csv),*.CSV", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened")
```

Adding both file types to parenthesis:

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*,*.csv), *.XLS*,*.CSV", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened")
```

Everything I try fails.

It is actually possible to do this right? It must be a simple mistake like a missing comma somewhere.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Seems like you were trying to get 2 filters working, when according to the response on the accepted answer, you actually want a single, combined filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, _
        FileFilter:="Excel/CSV Files: ,*.xlsx;*.csv", Title:="Select Files To Be Opened")
```

Extensions must be separated by ";".

You can find all parameters documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename).

Comment: Doesn't work, I can only see xlsx or csv files separately, not together. Same as my screen shot above.

Comment: Ups... I thought that the picture is what you need to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a File Dialog filter, instead?

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim myFile As String
Dim arrResults

With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select your files"
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel and CSV Files", "*.xls*,*.csv"  ' here is your filter

    ' Get your files
    If .Show = 0 Then Exit Sub
    ReDim arrResults(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        arrResults(i) = .SelectedItems(i)
    Next i

    ' If you set .AllowMultiSelect = False to only get 1 doc
    'If fd.Show = -1 Then
    '    fileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    'End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing

' Get multiple file names back out & do something with them here
For i = LBound(arrResults) To UBound(arrResults)
    'Do something with: 
    'arrResults(i)
Next i

' If you did 1 file
' MsgBox (myFile)
```